# What's the most efficient way to load k-mers into dict in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics

Currently, I have hundreds of bacterial genomes (fasta files), and I want to parse these fasta files then load k-mers from these files to a dict. For example,

A.fasta

```
>1 
ATAATA 
>2 
TTTAAA
.....
```

B.fasta

```
>1 
ATAAGA 
>2 
TTTAGA 
......
```

Then, the dict I want to get looks like (suppose k=4 ):

`d={'ATAA':{'A':'','B':'',...},'TAAA':{'A':'',...},...} # A refers to "A.fasta", B refers to"B.fasta"`

However, I find it's not efficient enough for my own code (see below)... Is there a more efficient way to achieve this goal?

```
    import re 
    import os 
    from Bio import SeqIO 
    from collections import defaultdict 
    import sys
    sys.path.append('..')
    from library import seqpy 
    def build_kmer_dict(idir,k): 
        print('Load k-mer to dict...') 
        dlabel=defaultdict(lambda:{}) 
        c=1  
        label_match={} 
        for filename in os.listdir(idir): 
            ff=idir+'/'+filename 
            seq_dict = {rec.id : rec.seq for rec in SeqIO.parse(ff, "fasta")} 
            for cl in seq_dict: 
                seq=str(seq_dict[cl]) 
                for i in range(len(seq)-k+1): 
                    kmer=seq[i:i+k] 
                    rev_kmer=seqpy.revcomp(seq[i:i+k]) 
                    dlabel[kmer][c]='' 
                    dlabel[rev_kmer][c]='' 
            label_match[c]=filename
            c+=1 
        return dlabel,label_match 
    # All genomes fasta files are in the folder "../Fasta_File_Dir"
    d, lm=build_kmer_dict('../Fasta_File_Dir',31)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to run seqpy.revcomp() for every kmer. Run the function once per sequence.

Comment: In that case, I need to iterate the raw sequence and the reversed sequence, and I am not sure the running time could be longer or shorter compared to "run seqpy.revcomp() for every kmer".

Comment: You're effectively doing that now. Except you're calculating rev_kmer for each iteration. This wouldn't be a problem if kmers didn't overlap. But if you have k=31 and an overlap of 1, rev_kmer is calculated about x30 more than needed. You should be able to use the same indexes without re-iterating. The range is comprehensive and order shouldn't matter. You can process seq forward and rev_seq backwards (relative; use same index range as seq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo code based on comments on original post. Process whole reverse complement at once instead of overlapping fragments iteratively.

```
import re 
import os 
from Bio import SeqIO 
from collections import defaultdict 
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
from library import seqpy 
def build_kmer_dict(idir,k): 
    print('Load k-mer to dict...') 
    dlabel=defaultdict(lambda:{}) 
    c=1  
    label_match={} 
    for filename in os.listdir(idir): 
        ff=idir+'/'+filename 
        seq_dict = {rec.id : rec.seq for rec in SeqIO.parse(ff, "fasta")}
        for cl in seq_dict: 
            seq=str(seq_dict[cl])
            rev_seq =seqpy.revcomp(seq) # calculate reverse sequence once
            for i in range(len(seq)-k+1): 
                kmer=seq[i:i+k]
                #rev_kmer=seqpy.revcomp(seq[i:i+k]) 
                rev_kmer=rev_seq[i:i+k] # assumes that order doesn't matter
                dlabel[kmer][c]='' 
                dlabel[rev_kmer][c]='' 
        label_match[c]=filename
        c+=1 
    return dlabel,label_match 
# All genomes fasta files are in the folder "../Fasta_File_Dir"
d, lm=build_kmer_dict('../Fasta_File_Dir',31)
```

Comment: Looks like this will be helpful. Thanks!